# C dynamic string array

Tags: c

I have char * lines[1000] string that can hold 1000 characters. How to create 100 arrays of that string. I get error with this code down.

```
char * lines[1000];
lines = (lines*)malloc(100 * sizeof(lines));
```

main.c:19:20: error: expected expression before ')' token

Comment: It should be a cast to `(char*)` not `(lines*)`.

Comment: It isn't clear what you want. What it isn clear is that `char * lines[1000]` isn't a pointer to a string of 1000 characters but is a pointer to a pointer of an array of char. It's a `char**.`

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is:

```
char lines[100][1000];
```

Alternatively:

```
char* lines[100];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  lines[i] = malloc(1000);
}
...
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  free(lines[i]);
}
```

The latter is a bit more flexible in that -- with minor modifications -- it permits you to allocate a different amount of memory for every string.

Comment: Realistically, they always will, but its worth noting that this depends on `char`s being a single byte.

Comment: @Aaron `sizeof(char)` is by definition equal to 1. Other issue if whether one `char` value is big enough to store an actual character, using your current encoding.

Comment: @rodrigo There's a difference between the implementation you're using and the ANSI C specs.  Assuming a char is one byte is, according to specs, not portable.

Comment: @Aaron What the ANSI C does not guarantee is that a byte is 8 bits (its `CHAR_BIT` bits), but that a `char` is size 1 byte is guaranteed by definition. From C99 specs, 6.5.3.4.3: When [sizeof is] applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or signed char,
(or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want an array strings, each string holding at most 1000 characters.  There are some issues with your code.

1. You've declared an array of `char *`s but what you really want is a pointer to an array of `char`s.  For that, your declaration should be

   ```
   char (*lines)[1000];
   ```
2. On the other hand, you shouldn't forget about the `NULL` bytes at the end of strings, and should probably instead declare

   ```
   char (*lines)[1001];
   ```
3. To set the pointer, you'll want to use

   ```
   lines = (char (*)[1001]) malloc(100 * sizeof(char[1001]));
   ```

   or

   ```
   lines = (char (*)[1001]) malloc(100 * sizeof(*lines));
   ```

   the latter working because, with `lines` a pointer to an array of `char`s, `*lines` *is* a `char[1001]`.  Remember to make sure you didn't get a `NULL` pointer back.
4. At the end, you should `free` the memory you've `malloc`ed with

   ```
   free(lines);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a for-loop as:

```
char * lines[1000];

int i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    lines[i] = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(lines));
}
```

Don't forget to free-up the memory pointed by all the pointers

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    free(lines[i])
}
```

Comment: While this is what the code in the question implies, it does not seem to be what is actually being asked for (and doesn't make a whole lot of sense - why is the size of a char array dependent on the size of a pointer array?).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a 2 dimensional array?

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear. It must be dynamic array of n elements

Comment: please edit your question, so future visitors to this question may understand the answer more. :)